# angular 5 nested ngfor

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to add multiple form fields a the click of a button. For achieving this I am using an array so an element of an array is pushed at the click of a button and depending on the items in the array the form is generated. In that form I have a select field which is populated by another array. The fields are generated fine but the select is not populating.

app.component.ts

---

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { test } from './test';

  @Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  mytest: test[] = [];
  fields: string[] = ['First Name','Last Name','Email Address','Address1 ','Address2 ','City','Postal Code','Province']

  add() {
    this.mytest.push({name: 't',type: 't',placeholder:'t',values:'t'});
    console.log(this.mytest);
  }
}
```

app.component.html

---

```
<form #formRef="ngForm">
  <div *ngFor="let word2 of mytest; let in=index" class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select id="fe[in]">
          <option *ngFor="let f of fields">{{f}}</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="word2[in].name" name="name{{in}}" class="form-control" #name="ngModel" required />

      </div>
      <br />
  </div>
  <button [disabled]="!formRef.form.valid" (click)="add()">Add input</button>
</form>
```

test.ts

---

```
export interface test{
    name: string;
    type: string;
    placeholder: string;
    values: string;
}
```

Comment: i believe you have to use `[ngValue]="f"` in your option tag.

Comment: what is "index"

Comment: `word2[in].name` doesn't make sense. `in`is an index, and word2 is not an array.